# Why is my application crashing when I call reloadData on UITableView?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, subview

I have a UITableView whose cellForRowAtIndexPath is printed below. When I call reloadData on the tableView, the application crashes, and there is no clear EXC_BAD_ACCESS or anything - it simply returns to main. The problem has arisen since I added the label subview, which leads me to think there may be some problem with releasing the subview/reusing the cell.

Can anyone see what's causing the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Ed

Here's the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //---
    for(UIView *eachView in [cell subviews])
        [eachView removeFromSuperview];

    //Initialize cell label
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 25)];
    [myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0]];
    [myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    myLabel.text =@"Label";
    [cell addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: where do you reload the tableview?

Comment: When a UIButton is pressed, which is supposed to refresh the screen (it's a UITableView that gets objects from a server). I've found a solution, although I don't know why it works - I removed the for loop that removes subviews from the superview, and everything seems to work. Any idea why this might be?